# SQL, is there a way to return only 1 row after UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

For the specific needs of my application, I need to retrieve all the records between a date range and **I also need the record that comes just before**.

To do this, I use a **UNION** with the **TOP 1** instruction in my second **SELECT**, but unfortunately the second **SELECT** returns all the records which meets the condition without taking into account the **TOP 1**.

```
SELECT
    T1.Date,
    T1.Order_Number
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE T1.idCustomer = 12345
AND T1.Date BETWEEN '20231101' AND '20231130'

UNION

SELECT TOP 1
    T2.Date,
    T2.Order_Number
FROM Table1 T2
WHERE T2.idCustomer = 12345
AND T2.Date < '20231101'
ORDER BY Date DESC, Order_Number DESC
```

Comment: *without taking into account the TOP 1* can you clarify this - if you run you second query you are saying you get more than 1 row?? note you should probably be using `union all` and the ordering of your results is not guaranteed without an outer-select with an order-by

Comment: I think you might be confusing the source of the rows in your results. When using a UNION it is sometimes helpful to add a column that describes the record source like: SELECT 'From query 1' as source,... UNION Select 'From query 2' as source,...

Comment: Note that you need an ORDER BY to get the previous row.-

Comment: The query you posted will definitely not return 1 row unless the top SELECT returns no row.

Comment: The final ORDER BY applies to the complete (UNION) query. To order its second SELECT, a subquery is required. https://dbfiddle.uk/YgSfWzl2

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **subquery** for the *second part of your UNION* to ensure that `TOP 1` is applied correctly, and then apply an `ORDER BY` to the combined result.

```
SELECT
    T1.Date,
    T1.Order_Number
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE T1.idCustomer = 12345
AND T1.Date BETWEEN '2023-11-01' AND '2023-11-30'

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1
        T2.Date,
        T2.Order_Number
    FROM Table1 T2
    WHERE T2.idCustomer = 12345
    AND T2.Date < '2023-11-01'
    ORDER BY T2.Date DESC, T2.Order_Number DESC
) AS PreviousRecord

ORDER BY Date, Order_Number;
```

**UNION** applies to the combined results of both queries, and the **ORDER BY** clause at the end of the statement affects the entire result set, not just the second query.

Comment: If you have something unique to add to this topic, please transfer it to the dupe target.  When you answer duplicate pages, you prevent the Roomba from being able to remove unneeded pages.  I've tried to negotiate [alternative rules to be more welcoming of signpost questions and adding answers to them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427768/2943403), but the grumpy majority doesn't want it.  We are stuck with the platform that we have. If you do not remove this answer, then other humans will need to waste their time doing what the Roomba should have done.